# Hex form for a sha1 hash of a String?

Tags: string, haskell, hash, hex, sha

I need a sha1 hash of a string in HEX form. This is the basic code:

```
import Data.ByteString.UTF8
import Crypto.Hash.SHA1 (hash)

toArgs :: String -> (String,String)
toArgs str = let h = show .  hash . fromString $ str
    in (str,h)
```

Which produces the hash, but in a form like this:

```
$ toArgs "Hejsan"
("Hejsan","\"A\\CAN]]\\131\\168\\210|\\n\\NUL\\NAK\\187j\\181Q\\STX\\146o\\fP\"")
```

I tried converting it to HEX using printf:

```
import Data.ByteString.UTF8
import Crypto.Hash.SHA1 (hash)
import Text.Printf (printf)

toArgs :: String -> (String,String)
toArgs str = let h = printf "%02x" $ show . hash . fromString $ str
    in (str,h)
```

which compiles, but throws an exception when executed:

```
toArgs "Hejsan"
("Hejsan","*** Exception: Printf.printf: bad argument
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [base16-bytestring](http://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2015-03-08/base16-bytestring-0.1.1.6/Data-ByteString-Base16.html) package. Note that you'll need to turn your `String` into a `ByteString`, which I'd recommend doing as a UTF8 encoding. Altogether, this would look something like:

```
Data.Text.unpack . decodeUtf8 . Base16.encode . encodeUtf8 . Data.Text.pack
```

If you just stick with `Text` instead of `String` (which I'd recommend), you can leave off the `unpack` and `pack`.

Answer (score 3):

That particular implementation of `printf` in Haskell isn't type-safe. You've run into that problem. The `%x` specifier requires a number, but you're passing it a string.

Assuming you're using the `cryptohash` package, the best way to get a hex representation is using the functions in `Crypto.Hash`, something sort of like this:

```
import Crypto.Hash

sha1Hex :: ByteString -> ByteString
sha1Hex s = digestToHexByteString (hash s :: Digest SHA1)
```

Comment: @FredrikKarlsson In case you didn't notice, Carl updated his solution to answer that question.